# Phonebook GUI Conversion from VS 2013 to VS 2017 not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli

We created a Reverse Phonebook Lookup in our class. Our school system uses VS 2013 on our machines and I use VS 2017 on my home PC. The program built at school runs fine on VS 2013 but when I loaded it with VS 2017 and tried to execute it, I got the following three errors:

```
Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error (active) E0442 too few arguments for class template "std::array" GUIPhoneBook c:\Users\diabl\source\repos\GUIPhoneBook\GUIPhoneBook\MyForm.cpp 12

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C2976 'std::array': too few template arguments  GUIPhoneBook c:\users\diabl\source\repos\guiphonebook\guiphonebook\myform.cpp 13

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error C3699 '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'std::array' GUIPhoneBook c:\users\diabl\source\repos\guiphonebook\guiphonebook\myform.cpp 13
```

This is what I have in MyForm.cpp

```
#include "MyForm.h"
#pragma once

using namespace System;

using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]

int Main(array<System::String ^> ^args)

{

    Application::EnableVisualStyles();

    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);


    Application::Run(gcnew GUIPhoneBook::MyForm());

    return 0;

}
```

I am fairly new to c++ and building the GUI so I have no idea what this means. I searched this forum and read the solutions to problems that were kind of similar to this but they didn't work. Does anybody have any ideas on a fix? Thanks.

Comment: The error message refers to `std::array`, but the code you've shown doesn't seem to use `std::array` anywhere, indicating that the code you've shown probably isn't relevant to the error, so you'll probably need to find the code that's actually causing the error before we can help much.

Comment: Ok I'll add the MyForm.h which has the issue that you may think it is.

Comment: The error messages say its in MyForm.cpp at line 12 or 13.

Comment: The first code I posted is everything in my MyForm.cpp, theres nothing else. I just tried David Yaws suggestion and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am fairly new to c++...

Standard 'learning the language' warning: This isn't C++ you're writing, it's C++/CLI. C++/CLI is a language from Microsoft intended to allow C# or other .Net languages to interface with standard C++. In that scenario, C++/CLI can provide the translation between the two. If you're still learning C++, please do not start with C++/CLI. In order to effectively write in C++/CLI, one should already know both C++ and C#, and then there's still things to learn about C++/CLI. If you want to learn C++, stick with standard (unmanaged) C++. (In Visual Studio, create a "Win32" C++ project.) If you want to learn managed code, then I would use C#.

---

That said...

```
int Main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
```

I haven't investigated why, but for some reason VS2017 is finding `std::array` first, while VS2013 is finding `cli::array` first. As you can probably guess from the error message you're getting, those two classes take different template/generic parameters. (`std::array` takes a type and a size, `cli::array` takes a type and the size gets specified when the object is created.)

To fix this, you can explicitly specify the `cli::` in the declaration of main. There also might be a `using namespace std;` that needs to be removed, or adding `using namespace cli;` might work as well.

Comment: Awesome man, it worked. I will let my Professor know about this little trick as well, I really appreciate it. We haven't discussed CLI yet but I believe we will as I continue to study C++.